# require 'init' LoadError: no such file to load -- init

Tags: ruby, irb

Haven't touched Ruby for ages so this really puzzled me.

Started up irb. 
Then first line I ran was:

```
require 'init'
```

and I got this back:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- init
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have library with name 'init'? I think not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it quite clearly:

```
no such file to load -- init
```

So, either there is no such file (`init.rb`, `init.so`, `init.jar`, `init.rba`, etc. depending on the exact implementation of Ruby you use) or the file is not in a directory that is on the `$LOAD_PATH`.